# 辞書の配列[{},{},{}]から特定の値が入ったやつらを取り出す[{},{}]

Tags: python

```
cars = [{'colors':'black,red,pink'},
        {'colors':'blue,yellow,green'},
        {'colors':'blue,red,gold,white'}]
```

carsにはcolorsの他に色々なKeyと値が入っています。
colorsの値は見たまんまの文字列が入っています。
`blue,red,gold,white`

carsからcolorsのそれぞれ一色が入った辞書らを取り出すにはどうすればよいですか？
色を選択してそれに該当する車等にフィルターをかけるということです。

```
c = [x for car in cars for color in car['colors'].split(',')]
# cは["black","red","pink","blue","yellow","green","blue","red","gold","white"]


#   blue  2           重複を消したcolorsに多い順に並べた配列
for key, count in collections.Counter(c).most_commons():

    # 失敗例
    print(dict(filter(lambda x: x in key, cars)))
```

理想

```
# red [{'colors':'blue,red,gold,white'},{'colors':'black,red,pink'}]
#blue [{'colors':'blue,yellow,green'}, {'colors':'blue,red,gold,white'}]
#pink [{'colors':'black,red,pink'}]
```

わかりづらくて申し訳有りません。
carsから20台選択する　＝　cars[:20]
carsからredのある台数分を全て取得 = cars[colors['red']]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

それではリスト内包表記と正規表現で。

```
>>> import re

>>> color = 'red'
>>> [c for c in cars if re.search(r'(^|,)'+color+r'(,|$)', c['colors'])]
[{'colors': 'black,red,pink'}, {'colors': 'blue,red,gold,white'}]

>>> color = 'blue'
>>> [c for c in cars if re.search(r'(^|,)'+color+r'(,|$)', c['colors'])]
[{'colors': 'blue,yellow,green'}, {'colors': 'blue,red,gold,white'}]

>>> color = 'pink'
>>> [c for c in cars if re.search(r'(^|,)'+color+r'(,|$)', c['colors'])]
[{'colors': 'black,red,pink'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

ジェネレータで

```
from pprint import pprint

cars = [{'colors':'black,red,pink'},
        {'colors':'blue,yellow,green'},
        {'colors':'blue,red,gold,white'}]

def filter_by_color(cars, color):
    def extract_colors(car):
        return car.get('colors', '').split(',')

    for car in cars:
        if color in extract_colors(car):
            yield car

pprint(list(filter_by_color(cars, 'red')))

# [{'colors': 'black,red,pink'}, {'colors': 'blue,red,gold,white'}]
```